# "Selbst ist der Mann" - kann mir das jemand auseinandertüddeln?

Tags: grammar, phrase

Mich würde mal interessieren, wo die Redewendung "Selbst ist der Mann" herkommt, und wie sich dieser Satz grammatikalisch korrekt zusammensetzt. Insbesondere die Rolle des Wortes "selbst" ist mir nicht so richtig klar.

Comment: interssanter an der Frage find ich ja eigentlich "auseinandertüddeln" :P Hab ich in Bayern so auch noch nicht gehört. "auseinanderklamüsern" kenn ich, steht sogar im Duden, lol! Ach ja, um noch was sinnvolles beizutragen `Selbst-Selbstständig` als Kurzform würd ich sagen oder autonom synomym für selbst zu Goethes Zeit (?), die Dichter machen ja eh meist was sie wollen und den Sinn/Rest darf der Leser sich aus/denken...

Comment: @Hauser: Kannst mal sehen, ich wäre auf "auseinanderklamüsern" nicht gekommen, dafür ist mir "auseinandertüddeln" sehr geläufig ;)

Answer (score 13):

Es handelt sich hier um ein geflügeltes Wort, bekannt auch durch Goethes Faust II:

[image]

<sup>Quelle [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=PN9FAAAAcAAJ&hl=de&pg=PA258&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%22Selbst%20ist%20der%20Mann%22&sig=ACfU3U3qhYyd4GmhvdmAIrQ8LIQuSVja4A&edge=0)</sup>

> Selbst ist der Mann! Wer Thron und Kron' begehrt. Persönlich sey er solcher Ehren werth.

Allerdings handelt es sich um ein wohl noch viel älteres deutsches Sprichwort, da sowohl [Adelung](http://books.google.com/books?id=sJBEAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA43&dq=%22Selbst%20ist%20der%20Mann%22&hl=de&ei=rcHDTqLqBoig8QOJkvm1Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAA) (1801) als auch [Campe](http://books.google.com/books?id=P0mh_rVHR7wC&pg=PA404&dq=%22Selbst%20ist%20der%20Mann%22&hl=de&ei=rcHDTqLqBoig8QOJkvm1Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAg) (1810) bereits auf dieses Sprichwort hinweisen. Beide nennen [Friedrich von Hagedorn](http://books.google.de/books?id=0m5BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=hagedorn%20%22selbst%20ist%20der%20mann%22&source=bl&ots=c4IHK6NO08&sig=EN1fYP11R89LEi3uObZX-FbYbmo&hl=de&ei=KsLDTuyMJIzHtAb_t-XVCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA) (1769) als Quelle:

[image]